# Apt getting wrong nginx source

Tags: nginx, apt, dpkg

I'm working on updating Nginx on my server from 0.7.65 (Ubuntu 10.04 repo) to 1.0.2 (from the PPA). I installed it just fine, but I would like to add/activate some modules. I found [this tutorial for doing it with dpkg](http://www.antazy.com/2010/11/ubuntu-nginx-recompilerepack-deb-with.html), which works well for ensuring that it maintains the defaults that `apt-get` uses for things like install location, and would like to use it to do the same for 1.0.2.

However, when I run `apt-get source nginx`, it downloads the 0.7 source from the main repo, and when I run `apt-get source nginx-full` or `apt-get source nginx-common`, it selects `nginx` instead.

Is there any way I can force it to get the source from the PPA, so that I can use `dpkg` and not have to deal with hacking in the Debian folder that `dpkg` requires?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify version to apt.

For example: `apt-get source nginx=1.0.2`

Comment: Sorry it's taken me so long to respond. That worked to attempt to get the package (and it actually found it), but it didn't download it. It came up with `Ignore unavailable version '1.0.2-0ppa1~lucid' of package 'nginx'. Unable to find a source package for nginx`. 'apt-cache policy nginx` returns 1.0.2-0ppa1~lucid for the first listing of available sources and the Candidate.

Comment: Try with a wildcard: `apt-get source nginx=1.0.2*` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @mboehn's answer: you can see the available versions of a package (and which repositories they come from) with `apt-cache policy package`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-stable-lucid.list

```
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu lucid main
```